# Determining the point of OutOfMemory Error

Tags: java, memory-management

In Java, is it possible to accurately find the point at which `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` occurred?

I am looking to better understand exactly how much memory did my application took a claim to before failing

Comment: Does it throw an exception and dump a stack trace?  That should tell you exactly what the code was doing when the error occurred.

Comment: Kinda rough.  There are so many things happening at once in a JVM that it's hard to know which thread is the culprit.  The thread that breaks isn't necessarily the thread eating all the memory.

Comment: @AdamLiss The question is not about where in code the problem occurred. The question is, how much memory is "too much memory" for the application

Comment: How about `-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: "The question is not about where in code the problem occurred. The question is, how much memory is "too much memory" for the application" :This what you provide in Xmx. JVM will start your application with amount given in Xms and will go on to allocate a maximum given by Xmx. OutOfMemory will generally occur, when your application has already consumed round about Xmx and is refuse to free some memory after repeated running of Garbage collector. Refer:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html

Comment: If that's what you want to know, why does your title say something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could catch the OutOfMemoryError and ask the runtime as shown below.

```
try {
    //...
} catch (OutOfMemoryError er) {
    // this will tell you how much you have used
    long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    System.err.println("memory used "+heapSize);
}
```

(an OutOfMemoryError should occur when the heap runs out of memory)

if you have no idea where in your code it will fail, you could try register a shutdown hook and output the heapSize there.